# Error while moving data to Amazon Kinesis (Member must have length less than or equal to 1048576)

Tags: python-3.x, mysql-python, amazon-kinesis

My python code is throwing below error while moving the data present in Mysql database to Amazon Kinesis. This error is may be due to the large number of rows present in a table.It is working fine for table with fewer rows. Is there any way to resolve this error? Please advice.

> Error : botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the PutRecord operation: 1 validation error detected: Value at 'data' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length less than or equal to 1048576.

Below is the python code I'm using

```py
from contextlib import closing
from datetime import datetime
import json
import mysql.connector as sql
import boto3
import os
DB_NAME = 'test'
DB_USER = 'root'
DB_PASS = 'xxx'
os.environ['AWS_PROFILE'] = "kinesis_developer"
kinesis = boto3.client('kinesis',region_name='ap-southeast-1')

def get_tables(cursor):
     cursor.execute('SHOW tables')
     return [r[0] for r in cursor.fetchall()] 

def get_rows_as_dicts(cursor, table):
     cursor.execute('select * from {}'.format(table))
     columns = [d[0] for d in cursor.description]
     return [dict(zip(columns, row)) for row in cursor.fetchall()]

class dump_date(json.JSONEncoder):
     def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, datetime):
           return o.isoformat()

        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)

with closing(sql.connect(user=DB_USER, passwd=DB_PASS, db=DB_NAME)) as conn, closing(conn.cursor()) as cursor:
   dump = {}
   table = input("Enter name of the table to load: ")
   dump[table] = get_rows_as_dicts(cursor, table)
   kinesis.put_record(StreamName="KinesisStreamName", Data=json.dumps(dump,cls=dump_date), PartitionKey="default")
   print(json.dumps(dump,cls=dump_date))
```

Comment: Update, I am able to resolve this by sending only 2000 records at a time to kinesis

Answer (score 0):

By [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_Record.html), record's data has the maximum length of 1048576. The issue you are having is not directly related to the number of rows, but to the stringfied size of your object. If you try to send less rows, each with a bigger size, you would still have that issue.

This code split data to fit the size

```
KINESIS_SIZE_LIMIT = 1000000 # actually, it is 1048576

def send_chunk(chunk, partition_key, stream_name):
    data = json.dumps(chunk, default=str)
    data_size = len(data.encode("utf-8"))

    if data_size > KINESIS_SIZE_LIMIT:
        # If data is too large, we split them in 2 recursively
        new_chunk_size = int(len(chunk) / 2)
        send_chunk(chunk[:new_chunk_size], partition_key, stream_name)
        send_chunk(chunk[new_chunk_size:], partition_key, stream_name)
    else:
        records = [{"Data": data, "PartitionKey": partition_key}]
        kinesis_client.put_records(StreamName=stream_name, Records=records)
```